# RichTextBox Help saving *custom* links

Tags: c#, hyperlink, richtextbox, customization

I have implemented arbitrary links in my rtb using the CodeProject found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox). The links are not truly links but instead data that is looked up when clicked and returned expanded information on the item clicked.

This all works great.  The problem is when I try to save the data off to a database using the RichTextBox1.Rtf method the links are lost.  I end up with the value of the text but there is no link data saved off in the Rtf.  Is there no Rtf code for hyperlinks?  Is there no way around this issue?

I am considering adjusting my approach to something more in line with [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567618/custom-links-in-richtextbox) but I don't want to change everything around if I can find a way to save my custom hyperlinks.

Any suggestions would be great!

---------------UPDATE----------------

Before submitting I did a bit more digging and dug up [this blog article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/313fdc5e-de8f-4de2-a4cf-44e838795384) which discusses that RTB do not save hyperlinks so I guess I am SOL.  The only way around this is by saving off the text in hidden textbox and save that version to the db but that way gets clunky.  I think I will go with the [second option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567618/custom-links-in-richtextbox) I found and I thought I would post this anyway since data in StackOverflow seems slim on this topic.  Now I know why.

Comment: Are you saving your data to be loaded back by the same interface, or by another?

Comment: The same interface.  I ended up reg-Ex checking my rtb against the list of keywords on load.  This works fine for smaller text but when pushed takes a couple seconds time which freezes the app.  I don't think my app will be pushed to this limit and if it does the feature is a nice to have but not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize, Rich Text Boxes do not save hyperlinks in the .Rtf field (nor text).  The value of the display is saved but not the actual link.  Seems like a poor limitation to RTB's IMHO.

There are ways around this case, create custom links like [this fellow did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567618/custom-links-in-richtextbox) or re-evaluate your data on load searching for the keywords (the route I took since the data will never get too large to cause freezing).

The code I used to perform this is as follows and called on load:

```
            foreach (ListViewItem keyword in Keywords.Items)
            {
                System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex oKeyword = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"\b" + keyword.Text + @"\b");

                foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in oKeyword.Matches(rtb.Text))
                {
                    int index = match.Index;
                    int length = match.Length;

                    rtb.Select(index, length);
                    //This next bit is made available through the use of http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox
                    rtb.InsertLink(match.Value);  
                }
            }
```

Comment: richtextbox saves the hyperlinks in the RTF property... tested.

Answer (score 1):

**Since this is an old thread, I'll post this just for reference:**

Here's a (somewhat) recent solution found in the [comments](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox?msg=4855954#xx4855954xx) of the same article on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9196/Links-with-arbitrary-text-in-a-RichTextBox):

Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// This additional code block checks the locations of links
/// and desc. it via a string which contains informations of how many links are there
/// .Split('&')-1 and the select information .Select(.Split('&')[i].Split('-')[0],.Split('&')[i].Split('-')[1])
/// After we select the links we can SetSelectionLink(true) to get our links back.
/// </summary>
public string getLinkPositions()
{
string pos = "";
for (int i = 0; i < this.TextLength; i++)
{
this.Select(i, 1);
int isLink = GetSelectionLink();
if (isLink == 1)
{
//the selected first character is a part of link, now find its last character
for (int j = i + 1; j <= this.TextLength; j++)
{
this.Select(j, 1);
isLink = GetSelectionLink();
if (isLink != 1 || j == this.TextLength)
{
//we found the last character's +1 so end char is (j-1), start char is (i)
pos += (i) + "-" + ((j - 1) - (i - 1)) + "&"; //j-1 to i but i inserted -1 one more so we can determine the right pos
i = j; //cont. from j+1
break; //exit second for cont. from i = j+1 (i will increase on new i value)
}
}
}
}
this.DeselectAll();
return pos;
}
/// <summary>
/// This method generates the links back only created via InsertLink(string text)
/// and overloaded InsertLink(string text,int position)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="pos">the pos string from getLinkPositions</param>
public void setLinkPositions(string pos)
{
string[] positions = pos.Split('&');
for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length - 1; i++)
{
string[] xy = positions[i].Split('-');
this.Select(Int32.Parse(xy[0]), Int32.Parse(xy[1]));
this.SetSelectionLink(true);
this.Select(Int32.Parse(xy[0]) + Int32.Parse(xy[1]), 0);
}
this.DeselectAll();
}
```

How to use the code [sic]:

> when you are going to save the rtf, save the return string of getLinkPositions() to, when you want to load the rtf, just load it how you do, and then use the return string from 1st method to get the links bak
>
> Ex :
>
> Save:
>
> > some save var = richtext.rtf
> >
> > additional save value = richtext.getLinkPositions();
>
> Load back
>
> > richtext.rtf = some stream gets rtf
> >
> > richtext.setLinkPositions(additional saved value from
> >     some stream)

Answer (score 0):

Well, another problem is, that the `hyperlink` is 'saved' but the click event and the target gets lost...
Only the format and behaviour (cursor changes) is restored.
And if You operate on this restored chunk of text it all gets messed up. 
So before doin any 'restore' operations, You need to clean out the `<hyperlink>` stuff.

Prajakta Joshi made an example for autodetcting hyperlinks - it also contains a cleanup routine:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prajakta/archive/2006/10/17/autp-detecting-hyperlinks-in-richtextbox-part-i.aspx

Cheers, Stephan

Answer (score 0):

As the `Hyperlink` tags don't get lost with saving, another approch would be to scan the loaded document for these tags and reapply it's properties - the click event and the navigate uri.

```
void restoreHyperlinks()
{
    TextRange tr = new TextRange(_richTextBox.Document.ContentStart, _richTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
    TextPointer tp = tr.Start;
    bool bFound = false;
    foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in UrlRegex.Matches(tr.Text))
    {
        if (tp == null)
            tp = tr.Start;
        bFound = false;
        while (tp != null && !bFound)
        {

            if (tp.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
            {
                string textRun = tp.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward);
                int indexInRun = textRun.IndexOf(match.Value);
                if (indexInRun > -1)
                {
                    bFound = true;
                    Inline parent = tp.Parent as Inline;
                    while (parent != null && !(parent is Hyperlink))
                    {
                        parent = parent.Parent as Inline;
                    }
                    if (parent is Hyperlink)
                    {
                        Hyperlink hyperlink = (Hyperlink)parent;
                        if (isHyperlink(match.Value))
                        {
                            Uri uri = new Uri(match.Value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                            if (!uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                            {
                                uri = new Uri(@"http://" + match.Value, UriKind.Absolute);
                            }
                            if (uri != null)
                            {
                                hyperlink.NavigateUri = uri;
                                hyperlink.Click += Hyperlink_Click;
                            }
                        }
                    }
               }

            }
            tp = tp.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
        }
    }

}
```

The regex is:

```
private static readonly System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex UrlRegex = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"(?#Protocol)(?:(?:ht|f)tp(?:s?)\:\/\/|~/|/)?(?#Username:Password)(?:\w+:\w+@)?(?#Subdomains)(?:(?:[-\w]+\.)+(?#TopLevel Domains)(?:com|org|net|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|jobs|museum|travel|[a-z]{2}))(?#Port)(?::[\d]{1,5})?(?#Directories)(?:(?:(?:/(?:[-\w~!$+|.,=]|%[a-f\d]{2})+)+|/)+|\?|#)?(?#Query)(?:(?:\?(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)(?:&amp;(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:]|%[a-f\d{2}])+=(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)*)*(?#Anchor)(?:#(?:[-\w~!$+|.,*:=]|%[a-f\d]{2})*)?");
```

`isHyperlink` is another method for checking the URL - the code is taken from:
http://marcangers.com/detect-urls-add-hyperlinks-wpf-richtextbox-automatically/

Hope this helps!
Cheers, Stephan